# How to determine if an employee is a manager?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Using the table EMP, where MANAGER represents the employee's manager:

```
EMPLOYEE   MANAGER
1          NULL
2          1
3          1
4          2
5          2
```

How can I make a query that determines if an employee is a manager?

```
EMPLOYEE   STATUS
1          IS MANAGER
2          IS MANAGER
3          IS NOT MANAGER
4          IS NOT MANAGER
5          IS NOT MANAGER
```

Is it possible to do this without a subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `JOIN` the table on itself and use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.Employee, 
    CASE 
       WHEN M.Employee IS NOT NULL THEN 'IS MANAGER' 
       ELSE 'IS NOT MANAGER' END Status
FROM YourTable E
   LEFT JOIN YourTable M ON E.Employee = M.Manager
```

Use an `OUTER JOIN` to get all the employees and not just those that are managers.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/478cd/2)

Comment: +1. Exactly what I was writing as your answer popped up, this is how I would solve this situation exactly.

Comment: I noticed that you used `DISTINCT` in order for this to work. Also, I was joining them reversely (E.Manager = M.Employee). Why does it work this way? Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherMarkieta -- `DISTINCT` is needed because of the `JOIN` -- without it, duplicate records could be returned.  Joining the tables on E.Manager=M.Employee would only return the records where a manager exists.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of manager primary keys, just

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    MANAGER
FROM 
    EMP;
```

To get more information about each manager assuming that the table also has such things as the manager's name:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.employee, m.given_name, m.surname
FROM
    EMP m
JOIN
    EMP e
ON
    e.manager = m.employee;
```

I originally left out the manager's id, but I edited it to add it just in case the organization has two managers with the same name: John Smith, say.

If you want the status message, you can use a CASE call.

```
SELECT
    MANAGER,
    CASE COUNT(*)
        WHEN 0 THEN "IS NOT MANAGER"
        ELSE "IS MANAGER"
    END "STATUS"
FROM
    EMP
GROUP BY
    MANAGER;
```

Comment: My last suggestion is silly, as it won't show any employee id that doesn't appear in the manager column.  An outer join will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no. Given the structure you show, there's no way of showing that without a join/subquery/CTE, you could know if the person is the top of the chain with:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMP 
WHERE MANAGER IS NULL
```

But aside from that you need a join/subquery/CTE.

Comment: Same kind of problem I have. But I have 2 tables - employee and employeeManager. 

Employee table has 3 columns - employeeId (pk), firstname, lastname.

EmployeeManager table has 5 columns - employeemanagerid (PK), employeeid (FK references employee > employeeid), managerid (FK references employee > employee id, effectivestartdate and effectiveenddate

I need to display records as

Employeeid, firstname, lastname, isManager


IsManager column can have 2 values Y for yes and N for  no.

I need to find the status as of today. I.E. On the day query is run. 

Any help?